# NEW : the package conflicts with an existing package by the same name

Tags: android, build, build.gradle

I created two programs with a signature and two different names.

First app:

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ir.bitafaraz.dpnadpnaadmin"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.0"
    }
```

Second app:

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ir.bitafaraz.dpnadpna"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.0"
    }
```

My phone is `Samsung(A5 2017, android 6.0.1)`.

I can not install both of them together.

I also tried with two different signatures.

Comment: Uninstall both apps (or whichever one you have now) from your device or emulator, then try again. Perhaps you have some older edition of your app installed from before you modified the `applicationId` values.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have done this many times.

Comment: Use APK Analyzer in Android Studio, or `aapt dump badging`, on the APK files that you are using, and confirm that your `applicationId` is taking effect as expected. Also, where exactly are you seeing the error message that you have in your question title?

Comment: @CommonsWare When installing the app on the phone.

Comment: That answers "when". My question is "where": in Android Studio? In a pop-up dialog on the device? On the command line from running `adb install`? Somewhere else?

Comment: @CommonsWare  In a pop-up dialog on the real device.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155268/discussion-between-javadaskari-and-commonsware).

Comment: @CommonsWare I wrote more details in the chat room.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very interesting, I use the following library in both projects:

```
com.commonsware.cwac: provider: 0.4.3
```

Based on the link below:

https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ContentProvider/V4FileProvider

When I deleted this library, my problem was solved.

EDIT:

The value of the AUTHORITY field is the same in both programs, their values must be different.